# Blockchain. Using sub-wallets through the main wallet without any restrictions or commissions

Tags: ether, web3.py, python, bitcoin

What I mean:

*Alleged example:*

I have a *wallet "A"*. This is the *main wallet*. I want to creat *5 sub-wallets* (in real case it will be more than 10.000 sub-wallets) from the main wallet - *"AB"*, *"AC"*, *"AD"*, *"AE"* and *"AF"*. So i give one sub-wallet address to each of five payers  (*"AB"* to first payers, *"AC"* to second payers, *"AD"* to third payers end so on). They transfer coins to it. And i can see all this transfered coins on my main wallet *"A"* a single sum. So i can manage them from my main wallet *"A"* without any restrictions or commissions.

Can i do this ? Is there such a possibility? Share info or links to documentation, please. I need it with Ethereum and Bitcoin wallets.

If it possible i need algorithm how to do it in Python 3.7 with Web3 lib.
I have no same code because i don't know is it possible in general for Ethereum and Bitcoin wallets.
I need any info about it and will be appreciate all the help i can get.

Comment: There's no such thing as sub-wallets in Ethereum. Perhaps you can simulate that functionality with contracts.

Comment: @Ismael , about Ethereum sub-wallets i understand, thanks, but what about Bitcoin sub-wallets ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about bitcoin, perhaps it is better to ask there https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Ismael , oh , thnx, i didn't know that Bitcoin has separate branch